# Using midje provided in a let clause doesn't stub methods

Tags: clojure, midje

When I make a test using an outer let clause to structure some definitions and calls, the stubs don't work the way I'd expect. For example:

This test fails

```
(fact "blah"
  (let [x (meth1 123)]
    x => 246
    (provided
      (meth2 123) => 246)))
```

With this code

```
(defn meth2 [x]
  (prn "meth2" x)
  (* 3 x))

(defn meth1 [x]
  (let [y (meth2 x)]
    y))
```

Am I not supposed to use `let` statements with midje? I can't understand how to get these to pass without removing the `let`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your test would even fail if `meth2` was stubbed correctly since `(fn [] x)` returns a function, thus the fact `(fn [] x) => 246` will never hold.

Secondly, I think that `provided` is used to stub function calls only when *executing* the left/right-hand-side of facts. In your case that's `(fn [] x)` (and `x` is already evaluated at that point), as well as `246` (which is constant). `meth1` never gets called in the context of your fact, only beforehand.

To change that, you could do one of two things. Either you make the `let` part of the left-hand-side of your fact:

```
...
(let [x (meth1 123)] x) => 246
...
```

Or you make `x` a function that is evaluated when the fact is tested:

```
...
(let [x #(meth1 123)] (x)) => 246
...
```

I don't think there is a way to really *see* `provided` in action, i.e. like this:

```
(let [x (meth1 123)]
   x => 369
  (let [...]
    x => 246
    (provided 
      (meth2 123) => 246))))
```

A `let` wrapping facts seems to be executed before the first fact is touched.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Along with using contexts for setup and cleanup, instead of a let statement